# Show html with format in Liquid

Tags: html, liquid

I've been looking for a while for a solution to what I want to achieve.

What I want is to insert some html text into a Liquid html file, for example I have some HTML text I received and use it as a variable in my code.

Here is a snippet of what I want to achieve:

```
{% assign name = "<b>liquid</b>" %}

 {{ name }}
```

I have a var name with a HTML string in it, and i want to show it as:

**liquid**

but instead, all I get is <b.>liquid<./b> (without dots, I'm still new posting here).

I know that "strip_html" exists so HTML tags are removed and I keep the text, but I want to keep the HTML format from the string.

Is it even possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out how make it work.

I just had to put the html part inside a capture tag. With the example above it would be like:

> `{% capture name %} <b>liquid</b> {% end capture %}`

And it works, the html is correctly displayed.
Thanks to Tasawer Khan for the answer! I hope it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You can show HTML tags as plain text in HTML on a website or webpage by replacing < with   <  or &60; and >   with  > or &62; on each HTML tag that you want to be visible

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I actually want is to be available to receive an external HTML formatted text, and show it keeping the format in liquid. I can do it with short, but what if it's a long html text?

Comment: use replace to replace all occurances of < and >